# get virtual attribute for each nested object in an array of objects?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I know how to get a single virtual attribute, as stated in the Mongoose docs:

```
PersonSchema
 .virtual('name.full')
 .get(function () {
   return this.name.first + ' ' + this.name.last;
});
```

But what if my schema is:

```
var PersonSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
      first: String
    , last: String
    },

    arrayAttr: [{
      attr1: String,
      attr2: String
    }]
})
```

And I want to add a virtual attribute for each nested object in arrayAttr:

```
PersonSchema.virtual('arrayAttr.full').get(function(){
    return attr1+'.'+attr2;
});
```

Lemme know if I missed something here.

Answer (score 26):

You need to define a separate schema for the elements of `attrArray` and add the virtual attribute to that schema.

```
var AttrSchema = new Schema({
    attr1: String,
    attr2: String
});
AttrSchema.virtual('full').get(function() {
    return this.attr1 + '.' + this.attr2;
});

var PersonSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
      first: String
    , last: String
    },
    arrayAttr: [AttrSchema]
});
```

Comment: there's no way to do this without an extra schema? or i should say, extra embedded schema

Comment: @deusj Not that I know of, no.

Answer (score 8):

Sure, you can define an extra schema, but mongoose is already doing this for you.

It is stored at

```
PersonSchema.path('arrayAttr').schema
```

So you can set a virtual by adding it to this schema

```
PersonSchema.path('arrayAttr').schema.virtual('full').get(function() {
  return this.attr1 + '.' + this.attr2
})
```

Comment: if `arrayAttr` is an array of objects. Which object is this referring to? Or is `full` now a new attribute or key of each object inside `arrayAttr`?

Comment: full is a new virtual property on each arrayAttr object.

Comment: Great stuff!! However, I still struggling to make this filed appear in the JSON. I was trying to add `Schema.path('items').schema.toJSON = { virtuals: true };`, but in the parent's `toJSON` `ret` value still misses it.

Comment: UPDATE: `Schema.path('items').schema.options.toJSON = { virtuals: true };`, and now it works

Answer (score 4):

If you want a calculated value from all the array elements here's an example:

```
const schema = new Schema({
    name:         String,
    points: [{
        p:      { type: Number, required: true },
        reason: { type: String, required: true },
        date:   { type: Date,   default: Date.now }
    }]
});

schema.virtual('totalPoints').get(function () {
    let total = 0;
    this.points.forEach(function(e) {
        total += e.p;
    });
    return total;
});

User.create({
    name:   'a',
    points: [{ p: 1, reason: 'good person' }]
})

User.findOne().then(function(u) {
    console.log(u.toJSON({virtuals: true}));
});
```

Returns to:

```
{ _id: 596b727fd4249421ba4de474,
  __v: 0,
  points:
   [ { p: 1,
       reason: 'good person',
       _id: 596b727fd4249421ba4de475,
       date: 2017-07-16T14:04:47.634Z,
       id: '596b727fd4249421ba4de475' } ],
  totalPoints: 1,
  id: '596b727fd4249421ba4de474' }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should write

`this.some_attr` instead of `some_attr`

And you can't acces this.attr because there are in arrayAttr. So you can do for example:

```
this.arrayAttr[0].attr1 + "." + this.arrayAttr[0].attr2
```

**This is not safe because arrayAttr can be empty**

Answer (score 0):

My favorite solution to this is to directly reference the nested schema.

```
PersonSchema.paths.arrayAttr.schema.virtual('full').get(function() {
  return this.attr1 + '.' + this.attr2;
});
```

Something important to also note is that virtuals are not returned by mongoose schemas by default. As such, make sure to set the stringification properties on the nested schemas.

```
var options = { virtuals: true };
PersonSchema.paths.arrayAttr.schema.set('toJSON', options);
```