# How to use virtual on a nested field in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose in node.js. I have the following Schema.

```
const CustomerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true
    },
    addresses: [
        {
            addressType: { 
                type: String,
                enum: [ 'personal', 'shipping', 'billing' ]
            },
            street: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                trim: true
            },
            streetNumber: {
                type: String,
                trim: true
            },
            floor: {
                type: String,
                trim: true
            },
            apartament: {
                type: String,
                trim: true
            },
            cp: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                trim: true
            },
            district: {
                type: String,
                trim: true
            },
            city: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
                ref: 'City',
                required: true
            }
        }
    ]

});
```

I want to use **"virtuals"** to "add" a new field **in every object in the array addresses**?

How I can do this using virtuals? Is it possible?

I can achieve the same result using, but I would like to use virtuals.

```
const customerDB = await Customer.findById(idCustomer).lean()

        customerDB.addresses = customerDB.addresses.map((address) => ({
            ...address,
            addressDesc: mapTypeAddressDescription(address.addressType)
        }));
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: I've answered similar question recently. Maybe you would like to take a look at it, on how to create a efficient document - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71013664/mongoose-update-insert-value-into-array-of-objects/71013819#71013819

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial Hi Thanks for your response. I read your answer and it makes sense, but in this case I see apropiate store the addresses in the Customer collection. I could separate it in a different collection, but I am not sure about the benefits.

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests `virtuals` are not added to the MongoDB documents. They are used for computed properties on documents.

Suppose you have a User model. Every user has an email, but you also want the email's domain. For example, the domain portion of 'test@gmail.com' is 'gmail.com'.

Below is one way to implement the domain property using a virtual. You define virtuals on a schema using the Schema#virtual() function.

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: String
});
// Create a virtual property `domain` that's computed from `email`.
userSchema.virtual('domain').get(function() {
  return this.email.slice(this.email.indexOf('@') + 1);
});
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

let doc = await User.create({ email: 'test@gmail.com' });
// `domain` is now a property on User documents.
doc.domain; // 'gmail.com'
```

You should check the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html) for more details.

You can do something like this:

```
CustomerSchema.path('addresses').schema.virtual('fullAddr').get(function() {
  return 'foo'
})
```

Also, it is useful to check this answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630674/get-virtual-attribute-for-each-nested-object-in-an-array-of-objects) if the above one doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I am not sure if I was clear enough. I want to use this "computed property" inside of addresses array. I cannt do:

virtual('addresses.myProperty').get(function() {
  return 'foo';
}); I dont know if it is possible with virtuals.

Comment: Updated the answer check it.